# time a script with less than seconds

Tags: python, time

i have this script but counts from seconds while the scripts ends in less than a second.

```
import time
start = time.time()
p=[1,2,3,4,5]
print('It took {0:0.1f} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

`python 3.7` uses a new function that can do that. I have 3.6.5. How do i do that?

Comment: Try `time.clock()`

Comment: @RohithS98 `time.clock()` is not wallclock time on UNIX systems.

Comment: well really stupid thing i will say but if you just do a print(time.time()-start), its giving me results just fine

Comment: @AKX Noted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`time.perf_counter()`, available since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter), lets you access a high-resolution wallclock.

```
t0 = time.perf_counter()
time.sleep(.1)
print(time.perf_counter() - t0)
```

Comment: why the sleep part?

Comment: @user10092387 For demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't count in seconds. It counts in fractions of a second, it's just that the script ends faster than the precision allowed by the string formatted float, ie. much less than a second.

Try:

```
import time
start = time.time()
p=[1,2,3,4,5]
time.sleep(0.5)
print('It took {0:0.1f} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

Also, for shorter sleep you may want to increase the precision of your float formatter (eg `{0:0.3f}`), so that for shorter sleeps (eg `0.007`) you don't have a `0.0` printed to console.

```
import time
start = time.time()
p=[1,2,3,4,5]
time.sleep(0.007)
print('It took {0:0.3f} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

Or just remove the formatter entirely (As commented by Inder):

```
import time
start = time.time()
p=[1,2,3,4,5]
time.sleep(0.007)
print ('It took ' + str(time.time()-start) + ' seconds')
```

See here for more details of timer resolution: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html